# Simple calculate using inheritance and Scanner how i handle these Exceptions?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, java.util.scanner, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple calculator using scanner and inheritance too, after i insert two numbers and operator i found this Exception

**the Exception is :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextShort(Scanner.java:1987)
at java.util.Scanner.nextShort(Scanner.java:1946)
at calculator.simplecalc.<init>(simplecalc.java:18)
at calculator.simplecalc_inhe.<init>(simplecalc_inhe.java:7)
at calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:6)
```

My Java Code: first class is **Superclass** it name is **simplecalc.java**

```
 package calculator;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class simplecalc {

    private int val1;
    private int val2;
    private Scanner sca;
    public char op;
    public int result;

    public simplecalc () 
    {
        sca = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        val1 = sca.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Second number");
        val2 = sca.nextInt();
        System.out.println("choose an operator + or - or * or / ");
        op = (char) sca.nextShort();
        System.out.println(op);
    }

    /*use if operator not equal + or - */
    public char set_op()
    {
        op = (char) sca.nextShort();
        return op;
    }


    public int calsum()
    {
        return this.val1 + this.val2; 
    }

    public int calsub()
    {
        return this.val1 - this.val2; 
    }

    //i don't use setX and setX i write them because i use getX,Y

    /* public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.val1 = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y)
    {
        this.val2 = y;
    } */

    public int getX()
    {
        return this.val1;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return this.val2;
    }

}
```

*Subclass*: **simplecalc_inhe.java**

```
package calculator;

public class simplecalc_inhe extends simplecalc {

    public simplecalc_inhe()
    {
        super();
    }


    public int mult()
    {
        return this.getX() * this.getY();
    }

     public int div()
    {
        int z = this.getY();
        if(z == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        return this.getX() / z;
    }
}
```

*Main-class*: **Calculator.java**

```
package calculator;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        simplecalc_inhe cal = new simplecalc_inhe();

        if (cal.op != '+' || cal.op != '-' || cal.op != '*' || cal.op != '/' )
        {
            System.out.println("You must enter a vaild operator");
            cal.set_op(); //to set operator 

        } else {

            if(cal.op == '+' ) {
                cal.result = cal.calsum();
                System.out.println(cal.result);

            }else if(cal.op == '-') {
                cal.result = cal.calsub();
                System.out.println(cal.result);

            }else if(cal.op == '*') {
                cal.result = cal.mult();
                System.out.println(cal.result);

            }else if(cal.op == '/') {
                cal.result = cal.div();
                System.out.println(cal.result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope i explained that error well with most of details, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the Java doc itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextShort--) **:**

> *public short nextShort()* **:** Scans the next token of the input as a short.
>
> Throws:
>
> **InputMismatchException** - if the next token **does not match the Integer**
> **regular expression**, or is out of range

Because `+/-*` does not match as an `Integer`

Ypu maye use `op = sca.nextLine().charAt(0);`

---

And also, to use the return line properly, better do :

```
val1 = Integer.parseInt(sca.nextLine());
val2 = Integer.parseInt(sca.nextLine());
op = sca.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

---

Also your test if not good, because if you enter a '-', it will be different of '+' so true and you'll og into the `if`, in fact you need to og inot if it's different of ALL 4 possib, fix by :

```
if (cal.op != '+' && cal.op != '-' && cal.op != '*' && cal.op != '/' )
```

To ask the user until he give a good operator you can do like this : (but it will also ask again the 2 ints because it's the same method) / to avoid same code better put the `print` at the end, and use a switch, it's more performant :

```
do{
   System.out.println("You must enter a vaild operator");
   cal.set_op(); //to set operator 
} while(cal.op != '+' && cal.op != '-' && cal.op != '*' && cal.op != '/' );

switch(cal.op){
       case '+':
          cal.result = cal.calsum();
          break;
       case '-':
          cal.result = cal.calsub();
          break;
       case '*':
          cal.result = cal.mult();
          break;
       case '/':
          cal.result = cal.div();
          break;
      default : break;     //safety check
}
System.out.println(cal.result);   //try to not have SAME code written twice (or more^^)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is your problem:

```
    System.out.println("choose an operator + or - or * or / ");
    op = (char) sca.nextShort();
```

Neither + nor - nor * nor / can be read with `nextShort`.

You can use

> public String next(Pattern pattern)
>
> Returns the next token if it matches the specified pattern. This
>   method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous
>   invocation of hasNext(Pattern) returned true. If the match is
>   successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched the
>   pattern.

[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.util.regex.Pattern))

Comment: This method simply returns the next String token. so how i use it with char ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the Scanner designed to retrieve the line of values separated by white space characters. So if you want to read a character then use

```
op = (char)System.in.read()
```

this above line will fetch you the character you entered so that you need not bother about IndexOutofBoundException because you are not doing a get from index and no NullPointerException because you are playing with variables than objects.
So now looking at your code it is clear that you are writing a method  which accepts the character and does the operation so in that case you can just simply create a switch case and check all possible operations by case and throw error message from default case

so refactoring your code as

```
public void doOperation() {
 switch(cal.op)
{
    case '+' : 
        cal.result = cal.calsum();
        System.out.println(cal.result);
        break;

    case  '-' :
        cal.result = cal.calsub();
        System.out.println(cal.result);
        break;

    case  '*' :
          cal.result = cal.mult();
          System.out.println(cal.result);
          break;
    case '/' :
        cal.result = cal.div();
        System.out.println(cal.result);
        break;
    default : System.out.println("You must enter a vaild operator");
           cal.set_op();
           doOperation(); 
       }
   }
```

Comment: yeah i know switch it's easier simpler and more suitable for this example thanks a lot :) :) @harish

Comment: so could u tell me what can i do if i  insert a wrong op like #, the default statement  will tell me You must enter a vaild operator but i need to tell me that and insert a new operator then check it again i used continue; but it doesn't work , i think about it a lot but i can't reach for that mechanism :( @harish-barma

Comment: for that you have to wrap the method switch case in a method and call that method from default

Comment: I've updated my answer for recursively calling switch block if user has given wrong operator .

Comment: Really Good idea i think it's the best but i have i diffrent way by using for and initialize a variable then assign it twice one in the default case and another for the rest cases every time for found the default value recursive the switch case.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are saying but I don't